# Poner texto plano dentro de una etiqueta

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer algo simple, darle una regla de estilo a una parte de un texto

```
<span id="frase">la cancion me hace recordar una sensacion</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
   frase = document.querySelector("#frase").innerHTML
   frase.slice(-3) //ion

</script>
```

¿Cómo puedo aplicar una regla de estilo a la salida de mi función `slice`?

La idea es colorearlo para evidenciarlo de la palabra.

Si no se pueden aplicar estilos a un texto normal, entonces la posible solución sería poner la subcadena dentro de un elemento strong

```
<span>sensac<strong>ion</strong></span>
```

Comment: Mencionas que deseas colorear la salida de de la función slice pero no indicas dónde. ¿Lo deseas colorear en el elemento original? ¿Todas las coincidencias?

Comment: si deseo que lo haga en el elemento orgina, disculpa pero no entendi bien tu ultima pregunta, si te refieres a la seleccion de coincidencias de vocales y consonantes es otro tema, si tienes alguna idea para mi problema corriente no dudes en comentarlo

Comment: `ion` aparece dos veces, en cancion y sensacion. ¿quieres colorear las dos o sólo una?. En el comentario a la otra pregunta mencionas que no deseas usar expresiones regulares, deberías mencionar esto y todas los detalles relevantes en la pregunta.

Comment: bueno, para mi proyecto final lo ideal seria colorearlas ambas, pero en este caso no tengo definido ningun patron, al momento con la funcion slice puedo solo seleccionar io de sencacion, no puedo hacer mas que eso porque no me permite aplicarle estilos porque se trata solo de texto

Comment: Si no requires las negritas, hay otras etiquetas que se pueden usar, como span, font, por mencionar algunas.

Answer (score 4):

En el siguiente ejemplo se usa la etiqueta `span` y el atributo `style` para darle formato al texto extraído con `slice(-3)`.

```js
var frase = document.querySelector("#frase");
var fr = frase.innerHTML; //Variable auxiliar para abreviar un poco la siguiente línea
frase.innerHTML = fr.slice(0,fr.length -3) //Parte izquierda
  +'<span style="color:red">' //Abrir etiqueta para aplicar formato
  + fr.slice(-3)  //Texto a estilizar
  + '</span>';  //Cerrar etiqueta del formato aplicado
```

```html
<span id="frase">la cancion me hace recordar una sensacion</span>
```

Comment: se asemeja a mi solucion

Comment: tengo un problema cuando intento hacer lo mismo con un array de cadenas, deseo extrar dos elementos el indice 1 y el ultimo para aplicarle estilo

Comment: bueno si se trata de hacer lo mismo pero con un array, pensaba hacerlo en este misma pregunta

Comment: @steven: He borrado mis comentarios pues se han vuelto obsoletos.

Answer (score 2):

Una manera rápida es reemplazar, en el contenido HTML del elemento, las coincidencias con una etiqueta y una clase estilizada. Por ejemplo:

```js
const frase = document.getElementById('frase');
const fulltext = frase.textContent;
const html = frase.innerHTML;
const substr = fulltext.slice(-3);
const regexp = new RegExp(substr, 'g');

frase.innerHTML = html.replace(regexp, '<span class="highlight">' + substr + '</span>');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<span id="frase">la cancion me hace recordar una sensacion</span>
```

Si el texto es muy grande quizás se pierda algo de rendimiento porque cada vez que cambias el HTML de un elemento con esta propiedad, el DOM es reconstruído.

Comment: disculpa, pero aun no pensaba hacer uso de regex, lo queria usar mas adelante para buscar coincidencia entre vocales y consonantes, sin embargo no creia que desde ya fuese necesario, no sabia tampoco que fuese posible modificar el dom, no entiendo porque no se pueden dar estilos a un texto plano, no hay tampoco manera de encerrar entre una etiqueta dinamicamente, estas seguro que no hay otra solucion para marcar el texto sin regenerar el dom.  tampoco no me queda claro porque hay dos variables con el mismo valor, fulltext y html, que sentido tiene

Comment: @steven 1. ¿Por qué no usas expresiones regulares si ayudan con tu problema? Usa lo que te sea necesario. 2. CSS estiliza y solo conoce de elementos|etiquetas, no conoce el concepto de "texto" al aplicar reglas. 3. Si hay más formas, como usar DOMParser (más lento que innerHTML pero más seguro), pero para tu caso es irrelevante.

Comment: en base a tu respuesta se me ha ocurrido una idea, que tal si encierro el texto en un elemento, para que quede de la siguiente manera   <span>esto es una canc<strong>ion</strong></span>    como se podria hacer con la funcion replace

Comment: Yep, es una buena idea.

Comment: si pero como lo hago con la funcion replace, sin quitar ninguna letra, es decir la frase  "la cancion me hace recordar una sencac io n" crear un elemento<strong> despues de C y de N

Comment: Tendrías que sacer en qué posición hay ocurrencias y por medio del tamaño del texto que devuelve `slice` insertar el cierre de `strong`. Para los índices puedes usar el método `exec` de `RegExp` para buscar coincidencias y en cada match, usar la propiedad `index`: `let match = regexp.exec(texto); while(match !== null) { indexes.push(match.index); match = regexp.exec(texto); }`. Ese bucle guarda las posiciones (de inicio) en donde hay ocurrencias. A partir de aquí ya sabes en qué posiciones insertar los strongs.

Comment: uy parece un poco tormentoso, lo probare otro momento, gracias por la idea

Answer (score 0):

lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var elemento = document.querySelector("#frase");

    var frase = elemento.innerHTML;


    elemento.innerHTML = frase.slice(0,-3)+"<span style='background:yellow'>"+frase.slice(-3)+"</span>"
```